# Implement deep linking in android from single activity

Tags: android, indexing, deep-linking

Although I have gone through related document on google for app indexing

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/details

But still have confusion that If I want to receive incoming data on launcher activity and  from there If can take control and start relevant activity/fragment depending on some internal parsing over incoming url.

Answer (score 6):

You have to declare the action, category and data in a separate `<intent-filter>` tag, not in the same one with launcher specs.

```
 <activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="your.domain.com"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: With this approach my launcher activity opens two times

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure if I understood what your asking, so please correct me if I'm not answering your question.

Only the activity (or activities) that you put the intent filter in will catch an intent and start.  Therefore, if you only put the intent filter in one activity, only that activity will start, and not any of the others.  You can put multiple intent filters in the same activity to catch multiple intents.  You can also use the path segment of the url to send more information to your activity, and parse it in your activity.

Put the following in your manifest under the activity you want to launch (the path is optional):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.yourwebsite.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Use a url like http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourstring to open the app.

Then use `getIntent().getData()` to get the uri that started the activity.  You can then parse the uri to get yourstring.

Comment: I want to receive on launcher activity, this is hiding my application icon.

Comment: I don't understand, where is it hiding your icon?  Are you sure you put the intent filter in the right place in your manifest, inside of an activity tag?

Answer (score 0):

Add Following Intent filter to Activity you want to open via Deep linking  in Manifest.

```
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Then As per Intent data you get in Activity you can perform your action, too.